# Security check on BSC token

Tags: node.js, security, smartcontracts, web3js

I saw some websites / services that scan a specific BSC token address and get possible scam codes / vulnerabilities over the smart contract.

Do you know a service to implement this into my website? Basically, I'm making a system to set a score for specific token based on some checks (not honeypot, liquidity locked, etc).

I'm working with Node.js and Web3

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple APIs to achieve this. Honeypot.is API, DexScreener API etc are needed combined to make this work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).